# Is necessary any sanitization functions if I use the database layer correctly

Tags: database, security

In [Writing secure code](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code) said:

> Use the database abstraction layer to avoid SQL injection attacks

Then, my question:

When I get value for a user form is necessary pass to check_plain() or others sanitization functions, before I [use the database layer correctly](https://www.drupal.org/node/101496).

Answer (score 0):

The db abstraction layer, as you noted, should prevent SQL injection attacks.

[Check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) is actually used to make sure text is html safe. If your printing out user submitted data to the screen, it should (at some point) be run through check plain to [guard against cross site scripting attacks](https://www.drupal.org/writing-secure-code).